# echo environment variable with docker run

Tags: docker, environment-variables

Can anybody explain why this doesn't work:

```
# docker run -ti --rm golang echo $GOPATH

# docker run -ti --rm golang echo \$GOPATH
$GOPATH
```

when this works:

```
# docker run -ti --rm golang bash -c "echo \$GOPATH"
/go
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1) `docker run -ti --rm golang echo $GOPATH`

```
docker run -ti golang echo $GOPATH
/Users/me/go
```

I removed the `--rm` flag to be able to inspect the container. Then, I did `docker inspect container-id`:

```
"Env": [
    "no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16",
    "PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
    "GOLANG_VERSION=1.8.1",
    "GOPATH=/go"
],
"Cmd": [
    "echo",
    "/Users/me/go"
],
```

`$GOPATH` is expanded **before** the container starts. It's expanded by your shell, **indeed** before the `docker` command is called.

---

> 2) `docker run -ti --rm golang echo \$GOPATH`

```
docker run -ti golang echo \$GOPATH
$GOPATH
```

`docker inspect container-id`:

```
"Env": [
    "no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16",
    "PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
    "GOLANG_VERSION=1.8.1",
    "GOPATH=/go"
],
"Cmd": [
    "echo",
    "$GOPATH"
],
```

Here the `$GOPATH` is a literal string and doesn't get expanded by the shell because you escaped the `$`, then `echo` receives the literal var name instead of its value.

---

> 3) `docker run -ti --rm golang bash -c "echo \$GOPATH"`

```
docker run -ti golang bash -c "echo \$GOPATH"
/go
```

`docker inspect container-id`:

```
"Env": [
    "no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16",
    "PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
    "GOLANG_VERSION=1.8.1",
    "GOPATH=/go"
],
"Cmd": [
    "bash",
    "-c",
    "echo $GOPATH"
],
```

Here, your shell runs docker with no variable expansion too, due to the `\$`, but there is another shell that will catch it and expand it: `bash` will do that but inside the container this time, where the GOPATH is provided by docker as environment variable defined in the `golang` image (GOPATH=/go). See the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/64b88dc3e9d83e71eafc000fed1f0d5e289b3e65/1.8/Dockerfile#L45) where that is defined.